# Can I treat a class as a object type?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

I have a custom class say **class A** :

```
class A
{
     public testA:int;
     public testB:int;

}
```

Now, I have a object say **Object C** , the object has the exact same names of variables and everything as the class.

My question can I cast that object into class or vice versa. Instead of set/get of individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot cast an `Object` into a `Class`, but since a `Class` is an `Object` you can do the other way, but remember that accessing member from a `Class` is faster that accessing member from an `Object`.

To transform an `Object` into a `Class` you will have to instanciate the `Class` and then copy each `Object` field into that `Class`. But beware they will not be the same instance it's a copy.

To make the reverse you will have to use [describeType](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) on the `Class` to enumerate all the public field of that `Class`, and then copy the value into a new `Object`.

```
// simple sample:
class A {
 public var testA:int;
 public var testB:int;
}

function Object2A(o:Object):A {
 var ret:A = new A();
 for (var fieldName:String in o) {
   if (ret.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
    ret[fieldName] = o[fieldName];
   }
 }
 return ret;
}

import flash.utils.describeType;

function A2Object(a:A):Object {
 var ret:Object = {};
 var fields:XMLList=describeType(a).variable;
 for each(var field:XML in fields) {
  var fieldName:String=field.@name.toString();
  ret[fieldName]=a[fieldName];
 }
 return ret;
}

var o:Object = {testA:12, testB:13};

var a:A = Object2A(o); // copy from object into class

o=A2Object(a); // copy from class into object
```

Comment: Basically, I'm trying not to individually set the class items. Asked the question, to know if there is a way of escaping that :) Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. The rules of duck-typing (if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck) do not apply in AS3. Unless an object is explicitly constructed as type A, then a classification test will fail when compared to a generic object with the same properties. To cast generics into typed objects, I've always done this:

```
var obj = ((your generic object))
var a:A = new A();

for (var prop in obj) {
   if (a.hasOwnProperty(prop)) a[prop] = obj[prop];
}
```